# Bluetooth devices disconnecting when adding a new device

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

When trying to add a new bluetooth device like headphones or speakers to my Windows 10 box, it usually fails, and in the process disconnects existing bluetooth devices (mouse and keyboard).  I can't reconnect them until I reboot the machine.  Tried disabling the bluetooth adapter, resetting, etc.  Nothing works until reboot.  This has been a persistent problem through several Windows 10 builds (I'm on the insider loop).  Any thoughts on what might be causing this and what to do to fix?

Comment: So does this problem just exist on an RS5 build or do you encounter this problem with 1803?  If you only have this problem with RS5, then it sounds like a bug that should be reported, since there is likely an underlying conflict only Microsoft can fix.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think so, it's been happening since the earlier 1600's builds, if not before.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Bluetooth module of Windows 10 box comes with it? Or Windows 10 box Bluetooth module is given when buying a mouse and keyboard? Or other external Bluetooth module?

We can try to troubleshoot the following points:

1. Compare the Bluetooth version of the Windows 10 box with the Bluetooth version of other connected devices, try to use the same Bluetooth version.It may be a high version of the Bluetooth to support multi-device connections.
2. Bluetooth may only be connected to a fixed number of devices, we can use different devices to connect to the windows 10 box, and then detect whether the windows 10 box can be seen to connect up to several devices?
3. Or can the windows 10 box Bluetooth connect to the specified device?
4. Confirm with the manufacturer of the Bluetooth module whether the Bluetooth of the Windows 10 box can only connect 1 or 2 devices.